# Difficult problem of Maxima and minima

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers $$ x^2 + y^2 = 2x – 2y + 2.$$
What is the largest possible value of $$x^2 + y^2 – \sqrt{32}\; ?$$

I tried the problem by rearranging the equation as $x^2 -2x -2 = - y^2 - 2y$
As coefficient of $y^2 < 0$, maximum value of $x^2 -2x -2 = 1$.       [$(Y)max=-D/4a$]

Now putting $x^2 -2x - 3 = 0$, $x$ turns out to be $3$ or $-1$.
As $x^2 -2x -2 = - y^2 - 2y$ and $x^2 -2x -2=1, - y^2 - 2y=1$.
On solving, $y = -1$

Now putting it in $x^2 + y^2 - \sqrt{32}$, the answer turns out to be $10 - \sqrt{32}$.
But the answer is $6$.
How??

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not so difficult.

The equation $x^2+y^2=2x-2y+2$ can be rewritten as
$$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=4$$
which is an equation of a circle centred at $(1,-1)$ with radius $2$. The maximum of $x^2+y^2-\sqrt{32}$ on this circle is clearly attained where the maximum of $x^2+y^2$ is attained on the same circle, so we are looking for a point on our circle whose (square of the) distance to the origin is maximal. Elementary geometry reveals that such a point must lie on the line passing through $(0,0)$ and the centre of the circle, $(1,-1)$. The equation of this line is $y=-x$, and it intersects our circle at two points: $(1-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}-1)$ and $(1+\sqrt{2},-1-\sqrt{2})$. The second point is the farthest one, and the distance  squared is $2(1+\sqrt{2})^2$. Therefore, the original functions' maximum over the circle is equal to 
$$2(1+\sqrt{2})^2-\sqrt{32}=2(1+2\sqrt{2}+2)-4\sqrt{2}=6$$

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $x=2\cos t+1, y=2\sin t-1$

$$x^2+y^2=(2\cos t+1)^2+(2\sin t-1)^2=2+1+1+4(\cos t-\sin t)=4+4\sqrt2\cos\left(t+\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

Now as $t$ is real,
$$-1\le\cos\left(t+\dfrac\pi4\right)\le1$$